# character variable as parameter of function

Tags: r, loops, quantmod

part of my code for downloading financial data:

```
library(quantmod)

tickers <- c("XOM", "DIS")
stock1 <- getSymbols(tickers[1], from="2010-03-01", to="2011-02-28", auto.assign=F)
stock2 <- getSymbols(tickers[2], from="2010-03-01", to="2011-02-28", auto.assign=F)

pair <- merge(Ad(stock1), Ad(stock2), all=F)             # 'xts' object, merge adjusted close
pair.DF <- data.frame(pair)                              #  data frame
```

But I want to call function like this:

```
tickers <- function(x, y) {
stock1 <- getSymbols(x, from="2010-03-01", to="2011-02-28", auto.assign=F)
stock2 <- getSymbols(y, from="2010-03-01", to="2011-02-28", auto.assign=F)

pair <- merge(Ad(stock1), Ad(stock2), all=F)            
pair.DF <- data.frame(pair)       
}
```

And then:

```
tickers("XOM", "DIS")
```

Or something similar. But what I get is bad result. In this case "x" and "y" aren´t numeric, but character.
It seems to be easy, but.. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me: `x <- tickers("XOM", "DIS")`
`> all.equal(pair.DF, x)`
`[1] TRUE`

Comment: Yes, it runs. Sorry, my fail. I have function with a lot of loops. This is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tickers <- function(x, y) {
stock1 <- getSymbols(x, from="2010-03-01", to="2011-02-28", auto.assign=F)
stock2 <- getSymbols(y, from="2010-03-01", to="2011-02-28", auto.assign=F)

pair <- merge(Ad(stock1), Ad(stock2), all=F)            
pair.DF <- data.frame(pair)       
return(pair.DF)
}
```

Works for me as long as you return the pair.DF at the end.  Is that your problem?

I don't think the character class is the problem:

```
class(tickers[1])==class("XOM")
TRUE
```

Comment: Sorry for unnecessary question.
Thanks.